# How to run two asynchronus task synchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I am new to multithreading concept in java(springboot) and have a scenario to solve.There is a function in which 2 asynchronus functions are called.I want to make their execution happen synchronously.eg:

```
public void func(){

call1();
call2();
}

@Async
public void call1(){}

@Async
public void call2(){}
```

Can anyone please suggest a method to achieve this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to make synchronous, methods that are asynchronous, why are you using the @Async annotation then?

Comment: then,I guess the response time would be increased.

Comment: Are you asking about sequencing? So that Call2 will only execute after Call1? Or are you trying to block until both calls complete? Either way take a look at Java `CompleteableFuture`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure whats the motivation over here, but from what I could understand from the question, the objective seems like that you dont want to block the main thread (thread executing func()), and at the same time achieve serial execution of call1() and call2(). If thats what you want, you could perhaps make call1() and call2() synchronous (i.e. remove the @Async annotation), and add a third asynchronous method (callWrapper() perhaps), and invoke call1() and call2() serially in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait on `@Async` methods if you change them to return a `Future`. For example like this:

```
@Component
class AsyncStuff {
    @Async
    public ListenableFuture<?> call1() {
        /** do things */
        return AsyncResult.forValue(null);
    }
    @Async
    public ListenableFuture<?> call2() {
        /** do other things */
        return AsyncResult.forValue(null);
    }
}

@Component
class User {
    @Autowired
    AsyncStuff asyncStuff; // @Async methods work only when they are in a different class

    public void use() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        asyncStuff
            .call1() // starts this execution in another thread
            .get();  // lets this thread wait for the other thread
        asyncStuff
            .call2() // now start the seconds thing
            .get();  // and wait again
    }
}
```

But it's guaranteed to be slower than simply doing all this without async because all this adds is overhead to move execution between threads. The calling thread could instead of waiting for other threads to do things simply execute the code itself in that time.